# container query with height not work but can adjust with width

Tags: css, container-queries

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v423/h3vxjt06/)

Container query width is active but height not woking

```
#box {
      container: box/inline-size;
      height: 200px;
    }

    @container box (height > 50px) {
      /* not work */
      article {
        background: skyblue ;
      }
    }

    @container box (width > 50px) {
      /* it works */
      article {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
```

> height: The height of the container expressed as a  value.
> width: The width of the container expressed as a  value.
> This is the descprtion from MDN

I think the demo has no problem, it should be able to dynamically display the background color according to the height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you've specified `box/inline-size`, which would mean the `container` query will be based on the inline dimensions of the container( which can be thought of as its width also).

You'll have to use `size` instead of `inline-size` if you want to base your container query on the height. Something like:

```css
#box {
 container: box/size; /* here */
 height: 200px;
}

@container box (height > 50px) {
 article {
   background: skyblue;
 }
}

@container box (width > 50px) {
 article {
   color: blue;
 }
}
```

***[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e53nk48o/)***

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found some other problems while running.If I remove #box{height:200px}, the container query fails. The article list is a dynamic list, which may contain one or more articles. The articles may be one line or dozens of lines, so it's not easy to fix the height.  I hope that when the height of this article list exceeds 200px, only the first two lines are displayed, and all content is displayed when it is less than 200px.